# How to plot routes in python

Tags: python, plot, coordinate-systems

I have been studying Travelling Salesman Problem recently. I need to get route visualization on coordinate system. I have longtitudes and latitudes as series:
[[x_c],[y_c]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6lni.png)

I get the TSP solution, according to the solution my best route is:

```
best_route2
array([ 0.,  7., 10.,  8.,  9.,  1., 13., 11.,  5.,  6., 12.,  4.,  3.,
    2.,  0.])
```

I start plotting as follows. But i cannot find a way connected the dots in best route.

```
plt.plot(x_c[0], y_c[0], c='r', marker='*')
plt.scatter(x_c[1:], y_c[1:], c='b')
```

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLDUw.png)

How can I connect the dots in the following order?
0 - 7 - 10 - 8 - 9 - 1 - 13 - 11 - 5 - 6 - 12 - 4 - 3 - 2 - 0

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code snippet you could modify to meet your requirements:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#number of points
n_points = 8

#for the reproducibility purpose
np.random.seed(12345)

#an array to be used as the hypothetical order
myorder=np.random.choice(range(n_points), n_points, replace=False)

#sample coordinates
x_c = np.arange(n_points)
y_c = np.random.uniform(0,n_points,n_points)

#sorting coordinates
x_c_sorted=[]
y_c_sorted=[]
for sn in myorder:
    x_c_sorted.append(x_c[sn])
    y_c_sorted.append(y_c[sn])
    
#plotting
plt.plot(x_c_sorted, y_c_sorted, '--o')
plt.show()
```

[image]